# How to grep for a key in the file?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sh, rhel

I have a text file that carries the following values

```
Key 1: 0e3f02b50acfe57e21ba991b39d75170d80d98e831400250d3b4813c9b305fd801
Key 2: 8e3db2b4cdfc55d91512daa9ed31b348545f6ba80fcf2c3e1dbb6ce9405f959602
```

I am using the following grep command to extract value of `Key 1`

```
grep -Po '(?<=Key 1=)[^"]*' abc.txt
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.
Please help me figure out the correct grep command

My output should be:

```
0e3f02b50acfe57e21ba991b39d75170d80d98e831400250d3b4813c9b305fd801
```

Answer (score 3):

A `grep`+`cut` solution: Search for the right key, then return the third field:

```
$ grep '^Key 1:' abc.txt | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Or, equivalently in `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^Key 1:/ { print $3 }' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use grep to modify the matching string, that's pointless, messy, and non-portable when sed already does it concisely and portably:

```
$ sed -n 's/^Key 1: //p' file
0e3f02b50acfe57e21ba991b39d75170d80d98e831400250d3b4813c9b305fd801
```

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `grep` doesn't support *PCRE*, you can do the same with `sed`, e.g.

```
$ sed -n '/^Key 1: [^"]/s/^Key 1: //p' file.txt
0e3f02b50acfe57e21ba991b39d75170d80d98e831400250d3b4813c9b305fd801
```

Explanation

- `-n` suppress normal printing of pattern space
- `/^Key 1: [^"]/` find the pattern
- `s/^Key 1: //` substitute (nothing) for pattern
- `p` print the remainder

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your grep (change `Key 1=` to `Key 1:`)

```
grep -Po '(?<=Key 1: )[^"]*' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '(?<=Key 1: )[^"]+' abc.txt
```

seems to work for me.